# How do you add gestures to a UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, gesture

I want to implement right-to-left and left-to-right gestures on a view that inherits from UITableViewController.  I have the code for the gestures implemented in another view (UIViewController) and it works.

It does't seem like `touchesBegan` is even getting called.

Does anyone know know to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the SDK version.  In 3.2, use `UIGestureRecognizer`.  Prior to 3.2 use `touchesBegan` and friends.  This is especially true when dealing with a `UIScrollView` because `UIGestureRecognizer` will cancel `touchesBegan`.  So if you want to be forwards and backwards compatible you have to do both with a UIScrollView.

For your particular case, use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` or `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.  You will have to implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` to prevent the UIScrollView from canceling your gesture recognizers.

```
UITableViewController -> UITableView : UIScrollView
```

Comment: I'm running 3.1.2, do you know where I can get 3.2?

Comment: Or is there any way to do this without the gestureRecognizer?

Comment: You can get 3.2 by buying an iPad. Or wait a few days for 4.0…